# Empty extras in AppWidgetProvider's onReceive if passing a serializable object

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I'm trying to pass a serializable object that in my widget on click, in my WidgetFactory(extends RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory) I pass an object:

```
val fillInIntent = Intent().apply {
            putExtra(Constants.Widget.ITEM, item)
            putExtra(Constants.IntentItemPosition, 67)
        }

        itemView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widgetItemButton, fillInIntent)

        return itemView
```

And in my WidgetProvider in onReceive I get it:

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        when (intent.action) {
            Constants.Widget.ACTION-> {
                val exampleItem =
                    intent.getSerializableExtra(Constants.Widget.ITEM) as? ExampleItem
                exampleItem!!.let { // some code }
```

And in the line **exampleItem!!.let** {} it throws NullPointerException, due to empty extras. In my onUpdate method I set setPendingIntentTemplate:

```
val intent = Intent(context, WidgetProvider::class.java).apply { 
    action = Constants.Widget.ACTION putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
    }
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent , PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
widgetViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_listView, pendingIntent)
```

I already made logs, to check if extras are empty, they are. But if I comment the line **putExtra(Constants.Widget.ITEM, item)** and left only **putExtra(Constants.IntentItemPosition, 67)** I will succesfully get the passed nubmer 67 in my onReceive(if I wouldn't comment the line, I would receive only the default value). I could try to not use putExtra(serializable), and just put strings and integers, but I would really like to pass a serializable object, rather than passing a lot of strings and integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solving fot the problem, except of not using "getSerializableExtra" and "putExtra(Serializable)". I decided to put strings and longs/integers instead.